# GetQueuedCompletionStatus success on incompleted WSASend

Tags: sockets, io-completion-ports

I'm experiencing a strange behavior in my socket engine. Then engine uses IO Completion Ports with OVERLAPPED structs.

I send several packets using `WSASend` (one buffer per call) but sometimes I get a successful call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` where the bytes transferred is zero! If I make a call to `WSAGetOverlappedResult` (no wait) it returns `WSA_IO_INCOMPLETE`.

After a while I receive a new completion packet with the same overlapped struct, this time the bytes transferred matches the buffer length and `WSAGetOverlappedResult` returns no error.

Why the OS is generating a completion notification when the packet was still in the queue?

Comment: 'I receive a new completion packet with the same overlapped struct' :((

Comment: AKA 'you are misusing IOCP OVERLAPPED structs somehow'

Comment: Please show your actual code, or a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: Ok.To clarify. I have a CPacket class which holds the `OVERLAPPED` struct  (zeroed before `WSASend`) and the data. They are not reused in different calls. Keep sure the issue is not related to an invalid pointer or data being freed before the call completes. If I ignore those zero-bytes transferred write calls, the rest works as expected.

Let's say I call `WSASend` five times (with different data buffers and overlapped structs), in one or two of them, `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns it twice. One with zero transfer.

Although I can simply ignore them, I wish to know why they happen.

Comment: It should not .  I have never seen such behaviour:(

Comment: Time ago I made a patch for this and now I'm building a new code and hit the same issue but never knew the reason.